# Changing Activity to Fragment with sqlite db

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, fragment

I have recently tried to change a working sqlite populated listview activity into a fragment. I have made the changes needed but I continue to get errors that i dont understand. If any of you could help it would relieve serious frustration.

Here is my main activity

```
public class FoursFragment extends Fragment {

private DbHelper mHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase dataBase;

private ArrayList<String> userId = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> user_fName = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> user_lName = new ArrayList<String>();

private ListView userList;
private AlertDialog.Builder build;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.display_activity, container, false);

    userList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.List);

    mHelper = new DbHelper(getActivity());

    //add new record
    getView().findViewById(R.id.btnAdd).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),
                    AddActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("update", false);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    //click to update data
    userList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),
                    AddActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("Fname", user_fName.get(arg2));
            i.putExtra("Lname", user_lName.get(arg2));
            i.putExtra("ID", userId.get(arg2));
            i.putExtra("update", true);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    //long click to delete data
    userList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                final int arg2, long arg3) {

            build = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            build.setTitle("Delete " + user_fName.get(arg2) + " "
                    + user_lName.get(arg2));
            build.setMessage("Do you want to delete ?");
            build.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {

                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getActivity(),
                                    user_fName.get(arg2) + " "
                                            + user_lName.get(arg2)
                                            + " is deleted.", 3000).show();

                            dataBase.delete(
                                    DbHelper.TABLE_NAME,
                                    DbHelper.KEY_ID + "="
                                            + userId.get(arg2), null);
                            displayData();
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            build.setNegativeButton("No",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = build.create();
            alert.show();

            return true;
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    displayData();
    super.onResume();
}

/**
 * displays data from SQLite
 */
private void displayData() {
    dataBase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor mCursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "
            + DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null);

    userId.clear();
    user_fName.clear();
    user_lName.clear();
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            userId.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_ID)));
            user_fName.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_FNAME)));
            user_lName.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_LNAME)));

        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    DisplayAdapter disadpt = new DisplayAdapter(getActivity(),userId, user_fName, user_lName);
    userList.setAdapter(disadpt);
    mCursor.close();
}
```

}

Here is adapter that is called.

```
public class DisplayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


 private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<String> id;
private ArrayList<String> firstName;
private ArrayList<String> lastName;


public DisplayAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> id,ArrayList<String> fname, ArrayList<String> lname) {
    this.mContext = c;

    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = fname;
    this.lastName = lname;
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return id.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int pos, View child, ViewGroup parent) {
    Holder mHolder;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    if (child == null) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listcell, null);
        mHolder = new Holder();
        mHolder.txt_id = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_id);
        mHolder.txt_fName = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_fName);
        mHolder.txt_lName = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_lName);
        child.setTag(mHolder);
    } else {
        mHolder = (Holder) child.getTag();
    }
    mHolder.txt_id.setText(id.get(pos));
    mHolder.txt_fName.setText(firstName.get(pos));
    mHolder.txt_lName.setText(lastName.get(pos));

    return child;
}

public class Holder {
    TextView txt_id;
    TextView txt_fName;
    TextView txt_lName;
}
```

}

And here is the DBhelper.

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
static String DATABASE_NAME="userdata";
public static final String TABLE_NAME="user";
public static final String KEY_FNAME="fname";
public static final String KEY_LNAME="lname";
public static final String KEY_ID="id";
public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+KEY_FNAME+" TEXT, "+KEY_LNAME+" TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);

}
```

}

The error i receive is as follows

```
03-20 13:15:50.108: E/AndroidRuntime(795): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 13:15:50.108: E/AndroidRuntime(795): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 13:15:50.108: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  atapp.norman.tennis.FoursFragment.onCreateView(FoursFragment.java:52)
03-20 13:15:50.108: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:795)
03-20 13:15:50.108: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:998)
03-20 13:15:50.108: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
03-20 13:15:50.108: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1330)
03-20 13:15:50.108: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:417)
03-20 13:15:50.108: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
03-20 13:15:50.108: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-20 13:15:50.108: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-20 13:15:50.108: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
03-20 13:15:50.108: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 13:15:50.108: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-20 13:15:50.108: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-20 13:15:50.108: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-20 13:15:50.108: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I really don't mind if it is something stupid but really cant figure out what is going on! Thankyou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
//add new record
getView().findViewById(...
```

with

```
//add new record
view.findViewById(...
```

`getView()` in `onCreateView()` is too early - you haven't yet returned the view to the framework for `getView()` to return.